# How to send informattion to another php without going to the page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this button that sends the information to another php folder. but I want it to send but stay in the same page.

```
<button  class="btn btn-outline-dark w-60"><?php echo "<td> <a href='carrinho.php?acao=adc&id=$PegaID'>Adicionar ao carrinho</a></td>";?></button>
```

I want it to send but stay in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use AJAX.

You set your button to call a Javascript function. That Javascript function then launches the call to the URL: carrinho.php?acao=adc&id=$PegaID.

You can handle any returned data or just discard it. Usually, you would want to at least handle it so you can give the user feedback that the button was clicked and it accomplished what it was supposed to accomplish, or an error was generated.

Specifically, you will use XMLHttpRequest. Here's a link to a good write up to get you started.

[Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

1. Give your button an ID.
2. Remove your anchor.
3. Attach an ajax post to your button.

This is what your code should look like:

```
    <button id="adicionar" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-id="<?php echo $pegaID;?>">
        Adicionar ao carrinho
    </button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#adicionar").click(function(event){
        let id = $(event.relatedTarget).data("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: id},
            url: "another php.php"
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

If you're getting sent to another page just add `event.preventDefault()` above `let id=$(event.relatedTarget).data("id")`

It should look like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#adicionar").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let id = $(event.relatedTarget).data("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: id},
            url: "another php.php"
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In "another php.php" you'll want to receive the id with `$_POST['id']`.
Something like `$id = $_POST['id'];`. Then you can do whatever you want with the id in "another php.php".

Comment: do I put the code you entered in a function ? I never heard of Ajax before

Comment: So there's a couple of things you want to do. AJAX is a javascript function so you'd ideally want to enclose it in <script> </script> tags.
Also put it in a $(document).ready(function(){ INSERT HERE }); so that it doesn't break the DOM. I've edited the response to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to send data without referesh html page or change url.

ex:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
  <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc('$PegaID')">Change Content</button>
</div>
<script>
function loadDoc(PegaID) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "carrinho.php?acao=adc&id=PegaID", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code send data using get method. We send PegaID to the javascript function and then send data and then showing the result in demo using change html.